# Resolving a url inside Listview ItemTemplate a href

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, anchor

The URL in the databound object contains something like `"~/root/path/test.aspx?id=1".` (code below). I want to do  `Page.ResolveUrl` on it inside the `ListView`. Just can't get the syntax right. Can anyone help please?

```
<asp:ListView ID="DataLV" runat="server">

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
         <a runat="server" href="Page.ResolveUrl(<%#Eval("URL")%>)">View full data</a>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bring the databinding tags (`<%#`) outside of the `Page.ResolveUrl` method, and use single quotes around the `href` attribute:

```
href='<%#Page.ResolveUrl(Eval("URL"))%>'
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Now tell me how to remember this :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you mark your own quesiton as a favorite?

Comment: Yes I can. I just wanted to remember this without looking up. Thanks anyway.